# Combine nearby data by Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I would like to ask for oracle SQL syntax for the following scenario:
A table with columns for order quantity and shipment date. The data looks like this:

```
Qty shipment_date
10  9/20
8   9/19
3   9/18
5   9/16
2   9/13
```

To minimize shipping costs, I want to combine rows with shipment dates that are within 2 days of each other.
Can you please provide me with the SQL query for this? Thank you.

The expected result should look like this:

```
Qty shipment_date
2   9/13
8   9/18
18  9/20
```

Comment: `9/18` is at the same distance from `9/20`  as `9/16` from `9/18`. How do you decide what should be combined and what not?

Comment: I think is ok to do either combine `9/16` with `9/18` or `9/20`, just  combining all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY shipment_date
  MEASURES
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
    LAST(shipment_date) AS shipment_date
  PATTERN (first_day within_two_days*)
  DEFINE
    within_two_days AS shipment_date <= FIRST(shipment_date) + INTERVAL '2' DAY
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Qty, shipment_date) AS
SELECT 10, DATE '2023-09-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, DATE '2023-09-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, DATE '2023-09-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, DATE '2023-09-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, DATE '2023-09-13' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| QTY | SHIPMENT_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-09-13 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 |
| 18 | 2023-09-20 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OcJPWBKD)